# Can Epub file reader be made in ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, epub

i have an existing application , and now i want to include epub file reading functionality into the app. I am not getting any base from which i can get a clue to make it happen. i am referring to some of links but not been able to achieve desired results:
[this](http://blog.rhesoft.com/2014/05/21/cordovaphonegap-ebook-reader-for-web-and-mobile-with-epub-js-plugin/) is the link i am using.[this](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js) is one more that i am using. 
kindly help

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Comment: when i included the code in my HTML it's showing "unnamed reference book" . however when i am using browser things are working fine. after adding android platform it just stops.

Comment: I didn't use this but saw it in github https://github.com/pipacs/ionic